# @EnableIntegration disables @Cacheable

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cache

I am developing a Spring 5.0.0 RC3 based MVC web application using `@Cacheable` for performance reasons in many repositories:

```
package com.example;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableScheduling
@EnableCaching(order = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
public class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer, SchedulingConfigurer, CachingConfigurer
{
   ...
}
```

Now, after creating a second configuration for Spring Integration (tested with 4.3.11.RELEASE or 5.0.0.M6), the caching does no more work (=Spring **ignores** the `@Cacheable` annotations and jumps every time into the formerly cached methods).

Here is my integration configuration skeleton:

```
package com.example.integration;

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class OrderIntegrationConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
    public IntegrationFlow processOrders()
    {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("order.input")
                               .channel(orderChannel())
                               .filter(Order.class, o -> o != null)
                               .handle(ediOrderHandler())
                               .handle(mailOrderHandler())
                               .get();
    }


    @Bean
    public MessageHandler ediOrderHandler()
    {
        return new ServiceActivatingHandler(message ->
        {
            doSomething(message);
        });
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler mailOrderHandler()
    {
        return new ServiceActivatingHandler(message ->
        {
            doSomething(message);
        });
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel orderChannel()
    {
        return new ExecutorChannel(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    }
}
```

Removing the `@EnableIntegration` restores caching functionality but disables the whole Integration functionality of course.

The log files are clean - no exceptions/warn/error logs.

I am quite sure that I am doing something very wrong, but I don't know what it could be. Any suggestions?

---

Update 2017/08/30:

Here is the stack trace **without** `@EnableIntegration` annotated on my `@Configuration`:

```
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.example.config.PlatformConfigRepository.getAll(PlatformConfigRepository.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.example.cache.AppCacheLoader.load(AppCacheLoader.java:57)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache$BoundedLocalLoadingCache.lambda$new$0(BoundedLocalCache.java:3311)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.lambda$doComputeIfAbsent$14(BoundedLocalCache.java:2034)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.compute(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1853)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.doComputeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2032)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.BoundedLocalCache.computeIfAbsent(BoundedLocalCache.java:2015)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalCache.computeIfAbsent(LocalCache.java:113)
    at com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalLoadingCache.java:67)
    at org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCache.get(CaffeineCache.java:88)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:73)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:527)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:492)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:374)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:316)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
    at com.example.config.PlatformConfigRepository$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9c0006d6.getAll(<generated>)
    at com.example.config.PlatformConfigService.getAll(PlatformConfigService.java:59)
    at com.example.config.PlatformConfigService.getById(PlatformConfigService.java:71)
    at com.example.user.ConfigBasedRole.getPlatformConfig(ConfigBasedRole.java:43)
    at com.example.user.BranchRole.getBranch(BranchRole.java:55)
    at com.example.spring.controller.BaseController.getBranch(BaseController.java:177)
    at com.example.item.search.SearchController.getObjComfortSearchParameters(SearchController.java:361)
    at com.example.item.search.SearchController.getObjSearchParametersForType(SearchController.java:344)
    at com.example.item.search.SearchController.getObjSearchParameters(SearchController.java:316)
    at com.example.item.search.SearchController.tireSearch(SearchController.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:869)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:775)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:981)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at com.example.i18n.UrlLocaleFilter.doFilter(UrlLocaleFilter.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.example.user.PasswordJailFilter.doFilter(PasswordJailFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.sec...
```

And here is the stack trace **with** `@EnableIntegration` annotated on my `@Configuration`:

```
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.example.config.PlatformConfigRepository.getAll(PlatformConfigRepository.java:59)
    at com.example.config.PlatformConfigService.getAll(PlatformConfigService.java:59)
    at com.example.config.PlatformConfigService.getById(PlatformConfigService.java:71)
    at com.example.user.ConfigBasedRole.getPlatformConfig(ConfigBasedRole.java:43)
    at com.example.user.BranchRole.getBranch(BranchRole.java:55)
    at com.example.spring.controller.BaseController.getBranch(BaseController.java:177)
    at com.example.item.search.SearchController.getObjComfortSearchParameters(SearchController.java:361)
    at com.example.item.search.SearchController.getObjSearchParametersForType(SearchController.java:344)
    at com.example.item.search.SearchController.getObjSearchParameters(SearchController.java:316)
    at com.example.item.search.SearchController.tireSearch(SearchController.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:869)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:775)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:981)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
    at com.example.i18n.UrlLocaleFilter.doFilter(UrlLocaleFilter.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.example.user.PasswordJailFilter.doFilter(PasswordJailFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.example.spring.controller.PragmaFilter.doFilter(PragmaFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.example.data.IpAddressFilter.doFilter(IpAddressFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core....
```

The called, cached method looks like the following:

```
@Repository
class PlatformConfigRepository
{
    ...

    @Cacheable("PlatformConfigRepository::getAll")
    public Map<Integer, PlatformConfig> getAll()
    {
        return something();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `@CacheAble` bean/method. Also, a stack trace within the cached method (with and without `@EnableIntegration` would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my initial post and added both stack traces as well as the skeleton of one example `@Cacheable` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce it with this simple Boot app...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@EnableIntegration
public class So45939192Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So45939192Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Bar foo() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    @Autowired
    private Bar foo;

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
//      System.err.println(foo.getClass());
        System.err.println(foo.foo("x"));
        System.err.println(foo.foo("x"));
        if (this.foo.getCalls() > 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cache disabled");
        }
    }

    public interface Bar {

        String foo(String in);

        int getCalls();

    }

    public static class Foo implements Bar {

        public int calls;

        @Override
        @Cacheable(cacheNames = "cache")
        public String foo(String in) {
//          System.err.println("here");
//          new RuntimeException().printStackTrace();
            this.calls++;
            return "foo";
        }

        @Override
        public int getCalls() {
            return this.calls;
        }

    }

}
```

The problem might be caused by a change in the order that `BeanPostProcessor`s run (I see you are also using transactions). You would need to enable logging for `org.springframework` and compare the steps used to create the application context.

BTW, it's generally better to have your cacheable class implement an interface so that a JDK proxy can be used instead of a CGLib proxy. My understanding is you need `proxyTargetClass=true` on `@EnableCaching` when there is no interface.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Garry. I don't know what the problem is/was but I was able to workaround it by removing the  `@EnableIntegration` from the class `OrderIntegrationConfiguration` and adding it to `MyConfig`.

I have also set `proxyTargetClass=true` but it did not fix the issue.

I am still investigating if an `@Ordered` annotation on both configs could also fix this problem.

Update 2018-01-09:
Unfortunately, I was unable to fix this problem and thus, because of my project's deadline, I was forced to switch to a more "manual" way excluding the surely great Spring Integration Framework.